# AWS AppRunner start command running multiple time

Tags: apache, amazon-app-runner

I am trying to run apache server on AWS AppRunner using my source code repository with **corretto 11** as runtime using the below start command
https://github.com/myanees284/apprunner-jmeter/blob/main/run_apacheee.sh

I could see the commands in the above sh gets executed and service gets deployed successfully as **running**. However after the deployment and health check, the commands are executed repeatedly.

Application log is here: https://gist.github.com/myanees284/db233e7e0d71eba4643f56c2e1bf87ec#file-application-logs2022-08-22t06_29_55-322z-2022-08-23t06_29_55-322z-json-L281

I am unable to understand why the code is executed multiple times when the service is already running?

Answer (score 0):

After your start script exists, the container stops as well. That's why App Runner starts a new container after

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I really like the abstraction which appruner provides. With that  in mind - I am trying a use case of running load test using jmeter tool, and exporting the results to s3 bucket - https://github.com/myanees284/apprunner-jmeter/blob/main/run_test.sh

Comment: In the above mentioned start command script - I am simply running bash server in port 8080 for service to become active and after that performing the load test, exporting the results to s3 bucket. I want this script to run only once. Not sure if Apprunner would be correct fit for my use case